# C++ Struct within Struct + deleted function error

Tags: c++

I have a header file in a project where I am declaring a number of structs. Some of the latter structs have members that are the types of earlier declared structs. I am aware that these member structs must be declared before they are used but I have encountered an odd behaviour.

In the file below I tried to add a new member to the second struct `(LUT)` of type `Coordinate`. As yo can see the bottom struct `libraryEntry` has a similar member; this has been the case for a while and has caused no problems.

```
#ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "Enums.h"

struct Coordinate {
    int X;
    int Y;
    Coordinate(int x, int y) : X(x), Y(y) {}
};
struct LUT {
    int offset;
    std::string hexCode;
    bool modifiedByTrojan;
    //Coordinate xyCoordinate; <======= Causes build to fail when uncommented
};
struct libraryEntry {
    int id;
    DeviceType deviceType;
    int offSet;
    Coordinate xyCoordinate;
    std::string hexCode;
    DeviceConfiguration deviceConfig;
    libraryEntry(int idNum, DeviceType deviceType, int offSet, Coordinate xyCoordinate, std::string hexCode) :
        id(idNum),
        deviceType(deviceType),
        offSet(offSet),
        xyCoordinate(xyCoordinate),
        hexCode(hexCode)
    {

    }
};
#endif
```

Adding the Coordinate member above causes the error:

```
'LUT::LUT(void)':attempting to refernce a deleted function
```

Why is this only happening in the second struct?

Comment: That's not the real error message.

Comment: @melpomene [Oh really?](https://ideone.com/f6k54m)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes, really. Your example doesn't contain "attempting", for example.

Comment: @melpomene "attempting"?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes, the word "attempting". What are you trying to say?

Comment: @melpomene What do you mean by "Your example doesn't contain "attempting"?" What is "attempting"??

Comment: @Rakete1111 It's a word. The link you posted doesn't contain it. ???

Comment: @melpomene Different compilers have different error messages :/ gcc: `use of deleted function 'Bar::Bar()'` clang: `call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'Bar'` VC++: `'Bar::Bar(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function`. They all refer to the same problem

Comment: @Rakete1111 I know. Why are you arguing a point I didn't make?

Comment: @melpomene then why are you saying "That's not the real error message"??

Comment: Because it says "refernce" (and no space between ":" and "attempting"), indicating that OP retyped the message (getting parts of it wrong) instead of copy/pasting the real error.

Comment: @melpomene Explaining that in the beginning would help the OP more, and won't be ambiguous. True, the error message is not exactly the same, but saying that it's not the real one is misleading in my opinion.

Comment: @Rakete1111 To me it's the same as retyping code into SO, introducing typos in the process. Debugging that is useless because it's not the real code (every character counts). Similarly, typos in error messages make them untrustworthy: What else did OP change?

Comment: @melpomene True, didn't think about that. Thanks :) You're completely right. I actually have seen people introducing errors when retyping/renaming things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the struct that works (`libraryEntry`), you have defined a constructor, and in your constructor you are initialising `xyCoordinate` using its two-arg constructor.

In the struct that fails to compile, you haven't defined any constructors, so you get the default no-arg constructor, which initialises everything, including your `Coordinate` member, using their default (no-arg) constructors. `Coordinate` doesn't have a default constructor because you declared a different constructor and that causes the default constructor to be deleted, hence your error message.